# Can't access static file from Spring Boot application running in Tomcat servlet

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

All I want to do is access a specific file in a Java class.  I am using Spring Boot 2.0.0.M7.  When I run from my development machine using `mvn spring-boot:run` then everything works well.  In that case I am using:

```
File jFile = new File("src/main/resources/static/folder/fileName.txt");
```

When I deploy this to a Tomcat server (8.5) as a war, the file is put into:

```
WEB-INF/classes/static/folder/fileName.txt
```

I've tried everything I could find or think of, but always get an error of some sort, usually a file not found exception.

My most recent attempt was:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("fileName.txt");
File jFile = new File(url.getPath());
```

That produces a null pointer exception with `url.getPath()`.

I have read about needing to access the servlet config, but couldn't ever understand that well enough to get it to work.  Does anyone have a clear example so that I can access the file both from the development context and the production context?  Thanks!

Comment: Try this 
File file = new ClassPathResource("filename.txtl").getFile();

Comment: @Anunay I had tried that at one point earlier.  It doesn't work like that, but it does work if I use `ClassPathResource("static/folder/filename.txt")` which I only discovered by trial and error.  Can you explain why I need to start with `static` when most resources say that Spring will find the resource if it is in the class path?  Am I missing some sort of needed configuration?