# Proper way to reference files for subreports and images in jasper report

Tags: spring-boot, jasper-reports

I have a Spring Boot application where I am using the Jasper Reports Library.  On the development machine, I could get both a subreport and an image with the path of

```
src/main/resources/static/[subreport.jasper | image.svg]
```

However, when packaging as a WAR and deploying to a Tomcat server, the path no longer worked.

What is one way that will work to allow the report to work both on the development and production machines?

Answer (score 4):

After much searching and trial and error, I finally have something that works.

Subreports are not too difficult.

1. Create a SUBREPORT_DIR parameter.
2. Set the default value to "static/".
3. When calling the subreport in the main report, use the expression `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"SubreportName.jasper"`.  If the subreport is in another folder, just add that in front of the SubreportName.

Images were a little trickier.  It might be different if your image is in the main report.  I had images in the subreport, and the image file was in the same directory as the subreport.  I thought it should work to use a relative path like `./image.svg`, but nothing along those lines would work.

I had the same problem trying to reference the main report. See [Can't access static file from Spring Boot application running in Tomcat servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592302/cant-access-static-file-from-spring-boot-application-running-in-tomcat-servlet)

From what worked there, it gave me the idea to try it with the image, which did work.  Here are the steps I needed to do:

1. In Jaspersoft Studio, add spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar to the build path.
2. On the subreport, add `org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;` to the list of imports.  In the jrxml, this looks like: `<import value="org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource"/>`.
3. Add a SUBREPORT_DIR parameter with a default value of "static/".
4. On the image, set the expression to: `net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getInstance(new ClassPathResource($P{SUBREPORT_DIR}+"image.svg").getFile())`.

I would have to think there would be a more straightforward way to reference files in a relative manner, but at least I know this works.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39320863/59087